# Do I have to file a return to be able to carry over a past capital loss?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, capital-loss

If I have no income for a year but incurred capital losses in a past year, do I have to file a return for each year following the capital loss (even if I have no income) in order to retain the capital loss carryover to use against capital gains in the future?

Comment: Is this a question about united states?

Comment: Yes. It's a question about the United States.

Answer (score 1):

In the US you'll need to file your tax return to establish your capital loss, and then to carry it forward either as [NOL](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p536) (for the $3000/year you can deduct from your ordinary income) or as carry-forward capital loss.

Comment: Not sure what NOL stands for, but what if there was no income?  Is it still necessary to file a tax return without income in order to carry forward a capital loss?

Comment: NOL is "Net Operating Loss". When you have no income, but deductions - you end up with negative income, which you can also carry forward to the next year and deduct from the income then.

Comment: Looking that up, isnt NOL carryover something for businesses, not individuals?

Comment: @sterid See the IRS Pub 536: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p536